# Dismiss low disk space prompt (Suspend, Power Off, Continue)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, disk-space

I'm running a Windows 7 virtual machine under VMware Fusion 5. The VM is out of disk space, and I'm getting the following prompt:

[image]

The prompt says:

> VMware Fusion has paused this virtual machine because the disk on
>   which the virtual machine is stored is almost full.

I'm then given choices to *Suspend*, *Power Off* or *Continue*. I've tried to continue, but the prompt immediately re-occurs. The *ad infinitum* prompt makes it impossible to free disk space on the virtual machine.

How do I permanently dismiss this prompt?

Answer (score 3):

This message has nothing to do with your VM's HDD, and is showing because your *host* machine doesn't have enough disk space remaining.

> ...the disk **on which the virtual machine is stored** is almost full.

(Emphasis mine).

You need to free up some space on your Mac's drive in order for the VM to continue.

Comment: Thanks. The immediate problem I was having was Prompt → Dismiss → Prompt → Dismiss ... (*ad infinitum*). I could not move forward with any actions because of the incessant prompting. Hence the reason I asked: ***How do I permanently dismiss this prompt?***

Comment: Yeah, well you would permanently dismiss it by deleting files from your Mac's hard drive to make space. Mine has a small SSD and I have to do this dance a lot :(. Although I have come across this http://superuser.com/a/339099/290632 which suggests you can in fact disable this check forever (but then it's your fault if your OSX disk fills up and everything explodes)

Answer (score -1):

try Increasing used disk space by VM in your VMware HDD `Option`. after solving the problem you can change the disk space to its previous values.